# How to use Python to communicate with NIC PCIe

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, fpga, nic, dpdk

I am testing a custom FPGA NIC and I need to send management information (such as header info for matching) and traffic data to it using a traffic generator from within the user space.

The driver built for the FPGA is a modified version of IXGBE with DMA support for management, and also supports DPDK for kernel bypass to achieve high throughput.

I am trying to understand how the various software (driver, userspace application, etc) should be stacked/connected to each-other so I can achieve the objective of reading and writing to PCIe on the NIC using set of scripts from user space?

I have also been looking at this project 
https://github.com/CospanDesign/python-pci
which is useful however based on Xilinx XDMA.

Would appreciate any help, pointers on this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the question is too broad. For such a broad question there is a generic answer: have a look at Inter Process Communication:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

There are variety of methods, like Unix sockets, shared memory, netlink etc, to communicate between user space processes. As well as a variety of methods to communicate between user space and kernel space.

Just pick the best for you and try to do something. If it fails, come again on SO and ask ;)

Comment: I hope you meant *netlink*.